# Spark randomly drop rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm testing a classifier on missing data and want to randomly delete rows in Spark.

I want to do something like for every nth row, delete 20 rows.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Every n'th row isn't *random*.

Comment: Well if n was a random number.

Answer (score 3):

If it is random you can use [sample](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample) this method lets you take a fraction of a `DataFrame`. However, if your idea is to split your data into `training` and `validation` you can use [randomSplit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.randomSplit).

Another option which is less elegant is to convert your `DataFrame` into an `RDD` and use [zipWithIndex](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex) and filter by `index`, maybe something like:

```py
df.rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda x: x[-1] % 20 != 0)
```

Comment: Hi Alberto will try that.  My aim is to simulate missing data,  so that I can see how  a classifier will perform on streaming data if there is data missing for a few seconds.